# using groovy templates in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, groovy, spring-boot

I am trying out groovy templates in a spring mvc project and running into some issues. My controller is returning a `Source` object which has some basic properties like id, name, directory etc and a `Set of Subjects` where `Subject` is another entity with some attributes.

First i tried embedding Source object in the model directly

```
return new ModelAndView("views/source", "source", source);
```

and in groovy template I tried accessing the model data by

```
h2 "Source $source.name - $source.directory"
```

This for some reason doesnt works I get the error message

```
No such property: directory for class: source
```

so it doesnt actually recognizes the appropriate type for Source object. Instead if i explicitly use a map for model and embed the Source object in the map then I am able to access the model data.

```
Map<String,Source> d = new HashMap<String,Source>();
d.put("source", source);
return new ModelAndView("views/source", "d", d);
```

now in groovy template I am able to retrieve data this way

```
h2 "Source $d.source.name - $d.source.directory"
```

So this is strange that I have to explicitly use a map but as long as it works.

--

The second issue is that if I try to access the Set of Subjects from the Source object in the model using something like

```
d.source.subjects.each {  
    h3 it.name
}
```

this works fine and shows the names of subjects but if I add another html tag aorund it like

```
div {
  d.source.subjects.each {  
    h3 it.name
  }
}
```

this doesnt works anymore and i get this error

```
(class: source$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3, method: doCall signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Expecting to find array of objects or arrays on stack
```

almost like by putting another component around it changes the context. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a Groovy bug to me, so make sure you are on the latest and don't have any old versions on your classpath. Does it work if you use the getter, like `source.getDirectory()`?

Comment: What version of groovy? Maybe you can share a minimal project?

Comment: sorry you asked for that earlier. Here is the sample project https://github.com/adeelmahmood/spring-boot-groovy-templates-test1 that reproduces the error. I am using spring-boot1.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: `author.getBooks()` works for me (`author.books` does not). Looks like a Groovy bug to me (so raise a ticket with them if you want to fix it).